# Java 8 on Mac and FreeBSD different File sorting order by modified data

Tags: macos, java-8, freebsd, java

I faced with strange problem with sorting Files.

Given env

```
Dev: Mac OS X 10.11.3 OracleJDK 1.8.0_45
PreProduction env: FreeBSD 10 OpenJDK 1.8.0_72
```

Code

```
public static String getLatestTag() {
    File tagsDir = new File("./.git/refs/tags");
    ...
    File[] tags = tagsDir.listFiles();
    List<File> tagsList = Arrays.asList(tags);
    Collections.sort(tagsList, (f1, f2) -> {
       if(f1.lastModified() > f1.lastModified()) {
          return 1;
       } else if(f1.lastModified() == f2.lastModified()) {
          return 0;
       } else {
          return -1;
       }
     });
     logTagsList(tagsList);
     String latestTag = tagsList.get(0).getName();
     Logger.info("Application version is: %s", latestTag.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
     return latestTag;
}

private static void logTagsList(List<File> tags) {
    if(Logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        Logger.debug("Tags found");
        for(File tag : tags) {
            Logger.debug("Tag: %s, Date modified: %s", tag.getName(), tag.lastModified());
        }
    }
}
```

Gives an output

At Mac:

```
17:49:50,601 DEBUG ~ Tags found
17:49:50,602 DEBUG ~ Tag: v0.97, Date modified: 1457277455000
17:49:50,602 DEBUG ~ Tag: v0.95, Date modified: 1455809758000
17:49:50,602 INFO  ~ Application version is: 0.97
```

At FreeBSD:

```
18:52:49,902 DEBUG ~ Tags found
18:52:49,903 DEBUG ~ Tag: v0.95, Date modified: 1456038720000
18:52:49,903 DEBUG ~ Tag: v0.97, Date modified: 1457277515000
18:52:49,904 INFO  ~ Application version is: 0.95
```

In both cases user who is running an application has read access to .git directory.

Steps to reproduce:
1) git init
2) bootstrap java application (or play framework 1.4 application for complete reproduce)
3) add given code
4) make 2 commits to git
5) label those commits
6) run application
7) examine logs

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got an error in your comparison: `if(f1.lastModified() > f1.lastModified())` - you are comparing f1 with f1 here. And if both files are not modified at the same time, you are always returning -1, no matter what you compare. And this leads to unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: …and to avoid such errors, use `Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified)` instead. Even if you have to do a manual comparison of `long` values, just use `Long.compare(first, second)`